# Can't catch error occurred in parent window from iframe

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, internet-explorer-7, try-catch

I have multiframe application, where each form opens in separated frame and can use some JS API from parent window. API can throw an exception (error), but I can't catch it in iframe. It is reproduced in IE8 only. I've checked it in IE8/IE9 and Chrome. e.g.:
test.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
      var g_fn = {};
      function onLoad() {
        g_fn.thrown_error = function() {
          throw new Error("Main window: error");
          return 1;
        }
        window.g_fn = g_fn;
      }

      function window_do() {
        try {
          g_fn.thrown_error();
        } catch (err) {
          alert("Error catched!");
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="onLoad();">
    <input type="button" value="do smth in window" onclick="window_do();"/>
    <iframe src="/iframe.html" />
  </body>
</html>
```

iframe.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
      var g_fn;
      function onLoad() {
        g_fn = window.parent.g_fn;
      }

      function iframe_do() {
        try {
          g_fn.thrown_error();
        } catch (err) {
          alert("Error catched!");
        }
      }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="onLoad();">
    <input type="button" value="do smth in iframe" onclick="iframe_do();"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is that an IE-bug? Any workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
g_fn = window.frameElement.g_fn;
```

Or this, if there are `iframe`s inside `iframe`s:

```
g_fn = top.window.g_fn;
```